# Type hint Pandas DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, type-hinting

How should I type hint in Python a pandas `DataFrameGroupBy` object?
Should I just use `pd.DataFrame` as for normal pandas dataframes?
I didn't find any other solution atm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DataFrameGroupBy` is a proper type in of itself. So if you're writing a function which must specifically take a `DataFrameGroupBy` instance:

```py
from pandas.core.groupby import DataFrameGroupBy

def my_function(dfgb: DataFrameGroupBy) -> None:
    """Do something with dfgb."""
```

If you're looking for a more general polymorphic type, there are several possibilities:

- `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy` since DataFrameGroupBy inherits from `GroupBy[DataFrame]`.
- If you want to accept `Series` instances too, you could either union `DataFrameGroupBy` and `SeriesGroupBy` or you could use `GroupBy[FrameOrSeries]` (if you intend to always match the input type in your return value) or `GroupBy[FrameOrSeriesUnion]` if your output type doesn't reflect the input type. All of these types are in `pandas.core.groupby.generic`.
- You could combine the above generics (and others) in many different ways to your liking.

Answer (score 6):

vscode type hinting was still not able to recognize the type by following the above example. Changing the import statement to below helped:

```
from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy
```